# Add-ADGroupMember cannot find global groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm running a simple command:

Import-CSV $myfile | ForEach=Object {Add-AdGroupMember -Identity $mygroup -Members $_.Alias}

It works if the group I'm referring to is Universal, but not if it's Global.  Is there a switch a need to use to make it find Global groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$myGroup = Get-ADGroup ... #Play with the search scope, etc until you can get $myGroup set.  It's a better cmdlet for searching for groups because of those options.
```

Use this page for more detail: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196 - Then, once $mygroup is what you want it to be, the next line would work fine, or could be modified to:

```
Import-CSV $myfile | % {$myGroup | Add-AdGroupMember -Members $_.Alias}
```